# command read from file not executed inside while loop because of pipe

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop, pipe

Why is pipe not being read from file inside a while loop. What is the workaround in the below scenario.?

```
$ while read -r cmd
$ do
$ echo $cmd
$ echo ----
$ $cmd
$ echo ---------------
$ done < commands

df -hT|awk -v OFS='\t\t\t\t' '{print $1,$2,$7}'
----
df: invalid option -- '|'
Try 'df --help' for more information.
---------------
df -h | wc -l
----
df: '|': No such file or directory
df: wc: No such file or directory
```

---

```
$ cat commands
df -hT|awk  -v OFS='\t\t\t\t' '{print $1,$2,$7}'
df -h | wc -l
```

Comment: Currently, the example you have posted would only print  `yourscript: line X: cmd: command not found` instead of the output you say it does. Your actual example used `$cmd` instead of `cmd`, but that got lost when you wrote the question. Consider always copying the code from your question and testing it in a new directory before you post it. That helps prevent this confusion.

Comment: @thatotherguy It's changed now.Thanks for pointing

Comment: Is there any reason why you're reading commands from a file with a while loop? Why don't you just execute the file as a script? That will allow multi-line commands to work properly.